# How to set a bold string to HeaderFooter.FirstHeader of an Excel File (epplus)?

Tags: c#, epplus, headerfooter

I have an `ExcelWorksheet` item in C# that I want to add a `firstheader` in **bold**. Please note that the header should not be in any row, the content will start at `Row1`.

I am adding the header like:

```
ExcelWorksheet w;
w.HeaderFooter.FirstHeader.CenteredText = "My Text";
```

However, I could not find out how to make the content: `My Text` bold. There is no `.Bold` or `.FontSize`, or `.Style` kinda property anywhere that I can set the font style as bold. I found the picture below in the documentation, but I am not successful to reach the `listitems` in the code as well.

[image]

I have tried to set my text as: `"<b>My Text</b>"`, but no luck, did not work. Couldn't find an example online. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try set following this. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
worksheet.HeaderFooter.FirstHeader.CenteredText = "&18&U&\"Tahoma,Regular Bold\" Inventory";
```

- 18: font size
- U: underline
- Font Tahoma
- Bold :))

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: @ErayBalkanli: Well played, my friend :d